# Finding a irreducible fraction

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, math

Given a positive integer `n`, it is asked to find the probability that one can pick two numbers`A` and `B` from the set `[1...n]`, such that the `GCD` of `A` and `B` is `B`. So my approach was to calculate number of pairs such that one is divisible by another. And the answer was expected to be **in irreducible fraction form**.
EXAMPLE:
`1 2 3`
OUTPUT:
`1/1 3/4 5/9`

```
long n = sc.nextLong();
long sum=0;
for(long i=1;i<=n/2;i++)
    sum+=(n/i)-1;
 long tot = n*n;
 sum+=n;
 long bro = hcf(tot,sum);
 sum/=bro;
 tot/=bro;
 System.out.print(sum+"/"+tot);
```

And my `hcf` function was:

```
public static long hcf(long n1,long n2)
{
    if (n2!=0)
        return hcf(n2, n1%n2);
    else 
        return n1;
}
```

But the compiler message was time-out. I think there may be some problem with the `hcf` function or there is a better and efficient method for finding the irreducible fraction. Since it was successful for smaller inputs, I think there is most probably an efficient method for finding the irreducible fraction form. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the range on n?

Comment: @templatetypedef `n` ranges upto `10^9` and number of test cases range upto `10^3`

Comment: For those first three values of `n`, the probability appears to be `(2n-1)/(n^2)`. Any chance there is a general theorem about that? Maybe something inductive?

Comment: If this is a "challenge" question submission, the "timeout" (which is a runtime error, not a compiler error) means you have to find a slick solution. Part of the point of many such sites, is that the naive solution will fail, and *that* is the real challenge for you to solve.

Comment: @WeatherVane....thats the reason I have asked this question here....maybe something comes by intuition like what bradimus said....but I wanted some kind of proof so that I can follow the same approach for similar questions...:)

Comment: As I have said before, if I could solve this problem, I would submit it myself, and leave you to jump your own fences.

Comment: If you are not going work on your coding skills, at least try working on your [Google skills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Probabilities_and_expected_value). <-- That was my first result.

Comment: Could you please explain your input/output?

Comment: @haccks...I could not get your question...

Comment: I am not getting your output as per the input you have provided in the question.  For input `1 2 3` your output is `1/1 3/4 5/9` ????

Comment: the answer for `n=1` is `1/1`, `n=2` is `3/4` and `n=3` is `5/9`....it depends on the only input...that is `n`

Comment: The probability that one *can* pick two numbers `A` and `B` from `1..n` with `gcd(A, B) == B` is always 1. There's nothing random there. Are you trying to find the probability that if you pick `A` and `B` *uniformly at random* from `1..n`, their GCD will be `B`?

Comment: @user2357112 .... my problem was to find out the total possibilities such that gcd is `B` divided by total possibilities.....

Comment: @yobro97 What is the time limit ?

Comment: @sasha I don't know for java.....but for `C` it is 3 sec...

Comment: @yobro97 see my answer. Run the code and check. Comment if any problems.

Comment: @yobro97 Can you give the source of the question.

Comment: @sasha Source - https://www.codechef.com/problems/COOLGUYS

Answer (score 3):

Your `hcf` function is not too slow. Instead, the problem is that you have a for loop which iterates `O(n)` times, which is quite a lot when `n = 10^9`. You can get it down to `O(sqrt(n))` by only counting cases where `B <= sqrt(A)`. That will give you about half of the cases, because usually exactly one of `B` and `A/B` is smaller than `sqrt(A)`. The only exception is you have to account for cases when `B * B = A`.

Comment: @your solution is correct. The accepted solutions follow your logic. Not sure why didn't the OP read the solutions of others from online judge when they were open.